# addEventListener for new elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

Consider a basic `addEventListener` as

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("alert")
  .addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert("OK");
  }, false);
}
```

where `<div id="alert">ALERT</div>` does not exist in the original document and we call it from an external source by AJAX. How we can force `addEventListener` to work for newly added elements to the documents (after initial scan of DOM elements by `window.onload`)?

In jQuery, we do this by `live()` or `delegate()`; but how we can do this with `addEventListener` in pure Javascript? As a matter of fact, I am looking for the equivalent to `delegate()`, as `live()` attaches the event to the root document; I wish to make a fresh event listening at the level of `parent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overly simplified and is very far away from jQuery's event system but the basic idea is there.

http://jsfiddle.net/fJzBL/

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    prefix = ["moz","webkit","ms","o"].filter(function(prefix){
         return prefix+"MatchesSelector" in div;
    })[0] + "MatchesSelector";

Element.prototype.addDelegateListener = function( type, selector, fn ) {

    this.addEventListener( type, function(e){
        var target = e.target;

        while( target && target !== this && !target[prefix](selector) ) {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }

        if( target && target !== this ) {
            return fn.call( target, e );
        }

    }, false );
};
```

What you are missing on with this:

- Performance optimizations, every delegate listener will run a full loop so if you add many on a single element, you will run all these loops
- Writable event object. So you cannot fix `e.currentTarget` which is very important since `this` is usually used as a reference to some instance
- There is no data store implementation so there is no good way to remove the handlers unless you make the functions manually everytime
- Only bubbling events are supported, so no `"change"` or `"submit"` etc which you took for granted with jQuery
- Many others which I'm simply forgetting about for now

Comment: very interesting points and I learned, but I think jQuery's delegate() has also have these disadvantages more or less.

Comment: @Ali no these disadvantages are specifically what jQuery doesn't have

Answer (score 2):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", evtNewElement, false);

function evtNewElement(e) {
    try {
        switch(e.target.id) {
            case 'alert': /* addEventListener stuff */ ; break;
            default: /**/
        }
    } catch(ex) {}
}
```

Note: according to the comment of @hemlock, it seems this family of events is deprecated. We have to head towards [mutation observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) instead.

Comment: NOTE: Mutation events are deprecated in the level 3 dom. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted