# Pure JavaScript add listener to new element loaded

Tags: javascript

I want idea about add listener to new element via AJAX:

For example, now I have

```
<a href="#">hello world</a>
```

I added a listener to every `<a>`, but when I load new element via AJAX, it didn't have the listener; I'm not entirely sure what the problem could be.

Is it that it doesn't call the function when a new element is loaded and add listener for all of the elements?

I know that in jQuery, we can use `$("class").on()`, but how do I use pure JavaScript?

Comment: its didnt show <a> a href in my question

Comment: you need to attach new listeners to your new elements, or use event delegation

Comment: When you append new links they don't have event handler attached to them. In this case you either bind event again to it or use event delegation.

Comment: yes yes i know they didnt have listener but i want idea about that 
i can write code for add new listener bout question i want best idea

Comment: oh my god this site change some of my question Z_Z

Comment: its not the "site", its other members who edited your question to be more readable and easier to understand. if you feel there is a drastic change which contradicts the question's point, feel free to edit the question and fix it.

Comment: i found answer here >> thanks for every on respone to me :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179841/addeventlistener-for-new-elements

Answer (score 2):

simply add new listeners to your dynamically added elements in the ajax success callback right after you add the new elements, or use event delegation which means that you attach the event listener to a static ancestor node which will monitor events on its dynamic children:

**1.Attach new listener after AJAX Version**

```
var options = {
    type: "POST",
    url: "someurl",
    data: "some arguments",
    success: function (response) {
        //... add the new elements here...
        //...
        //attach event handlers here
        var myElement=document.getElementById("myDynamicElement");
        myElement.addEventListener("click",function(){
            this.style["border"]="5px solid red";
        });
    }
};
$.ajax(options);
```

**2. Event Delegation Version**

```js
var myContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".container")[0];
myContainer.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    while (target != myContainer) {
        var selector = ".myDynamicElement";
        var className = " " + selector + " ";
        if ((" " + target.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(" myDynamicElement ") > -1) {
            alert("test");
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="myDynamicElement">New Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for respone i found the answer here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179841/addeventlistener-for-new-elements